# Roslyn - integrate analyzer into build avoiding double compilation

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm currently working on a code analyzer using Roslyn. I need to obtain the `Semantic model` of my solution, which requires a compilation to be made. I want to integrate this analyzer into our build process (we use MSBuild). Currently it will look like this:

- Our solution is built
- Analyzer runs, compiles solution and does its work

This will mean that solution is compiled twice which I'd like to avoid.
How can I achieve compiling only once?

Currently I'm thinking of making a console app which will compile the solution  with Roslyn, analyze it, and produce the resulting DLLs and output them, effectively replacing the current `compile` step with my own. Is this possible / reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a Roslyn Analyzer, which runs as part of compilation.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers)

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't know how exactly make an analyzer to run as part of compilation on build server

Comment: @AlexBuyny: Just add it as an analyzer reference to your project.